# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm getting this error. from this line:

```
ohlc[0][i+1] = ohlc[0][i] + dt.timedelta(days=1)
```

Here's it in context:

```
stock_price_url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/AAPL/data.csv?start_date=2015-06-01&order=asc&end_date=2015-08-01&collapse=daily'
source_code = urllib.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()
stock_data = []
split_source = source_code.split('\n')
for line in split_source:
    split_line = line.split(',')
    if 'Date' not in line:
        stock_data.append(line)


date, openp, highp, lowp, closep, volume = np.loadtxt(stock_data,
                                                      delimiter=',',
                                                      unpack=True,
                                                      converters={0:strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')},
                                                      usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5))

x = 0
y = len(date)
ohlc

while x < y:
    append_me = date[x], openp[x], closep[x], highp[x], lowp[x], volume[x]
    ohlc.append(append_me)
    x+=1

# the dates in my example file-set are very sparse (and annoying) change the dates to be sequential

for i in range(len(date)-1):
    ohlc[0][i+1] = ohlc[0][i] + dt.timedelta(days=1)
```

Was trying to do something similar to this line from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128647/matplotlib-finance-volume-overlay/13216161#13216161):

```
# the dates in my example file-set are very sparse (and annoying) change the dates to be sequential
for i in range(len(r)-1):
    r['date'][i+1] = r['date'][i] + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Any help would be really awesome.

Comment: So `ohlc[0][i]` is a `float`... what were you expecting?

Comment: Updated question, please take a look.

Comment: But that requires you to be starting with a `date`/`datetime` - perhaps your real question is *"how do I make some of this data a `date`?"*, which is likely answered by the relevant documentation.

Comment: i.e. this will only work if `r['date'][i]` is a `datetime` object

Comment: Thanks all of you, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

The error arises from attempting to add together two different datatypes - a float, and a date.

From a cursory google, the matplotlib.dates [num2date](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date) function may help in this case. The [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) may also be of help.