# Matplotlib - Overlaying charts but with different box size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting `Revenues` and `Volume` across `dates`, with `Revenues` as `graph` and `Volume` as `bar`. All, I want is the `bars` should be plotted in the lower `30%` of the plot and not encompassing the entire plot. I think, that can be done with [`matplotlib.transforms.Bbox`](https://463-1385122-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/home/circleci/project/doc/build/html/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_box.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_box) but I don't know how. The following is the code:

Data can be found [`here`](https://pythondata.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/sales.csv).

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(20,10) # set the figure size
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight') # using the fivethirtyeight matplotlib theme

sales = pd.read_csv('sales.csv') # Read the data in
sales.Date = pd.to_datetime(sales.Date) #set the date column to datetime
sales.set_index('Date', inplace=True) #set the index to the date column
print(sales)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # set up the 2nd axis
ax1.plot(sales.Sales_Dollars) #plot the Revenue on axis #1

#ax2.set_position(matplotlib.transforms.Bbox([[0.125,0.1],[0.9,0.32]]))
ax2.bar(sales.index, sales.Quantity,width=20, alpha=0.2, color='orange')
ax2.grid(b=False) # turn off grid #2

ax1.set_title('Monthly Sales Revenue vs Number of Items Sold Per Month')
ax1.set_ylabel('Monthly Sales Revenue')
ax2.set_ylabel('Number of Items Sold')

plt.show()
print('Done!')
```

Following is the plot. I want that the `bars` should be plotted only in the `red` box (bottom `30%` of the height) I have marked, insteading spanning the entire height. May be, I have to do something like `ax2.set_position(matplotlib.transforms.Bbox([[...],[...]]))`, but don't know how!!

[image: plot]

Comment: Wouldn't that be achieved by setting the limits, like `ax2.set_ylim(0, sales.Quantity.max() / 0.3)`?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of something similar to scale down (though not exactly what you suggested). I tried your suggestion but the scale on right hand side `Number of items sold` goes from 1-> 14000. I am looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128647/matplotlib-finance-volume-overlay). Check the answer by @ljk07 and the plot he created.

Answer (score 0):

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
bb = ax1.get_position()
ax2 = fig.add_axes([bb.x0, bb.y0, bb.width, bb.height*0.3])
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I placed this code between `ax1.plot(..)` and `ax2.bar(..)`, but it gave a strange result. 1) Along right-hand-side, there are two scales. `0->1` is scaled from bottom to top in addition to `volume` `0 -> 4000` in bottom `30%`. 2) The graph in blue is invisible in bottom `30%`. It is as if bars are superimposed on graph in bottom `30 %`, with later not visible anymore.